# How to simulate a laggy web server in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, mocking

I am trying to create tooling to simulate scenarios of slow webservers.

### Motivation for creating mock server

- Our frontend app talks to 3 webservers - `X` `Y` and `Z` via same domain. `example.com/api/X/` `example.com/api/Y` and so on.
- We saw our web server `X` was taking upto 50 seconds to respond to HTTP requests.
- It was also taking upto 1 minute even for **establishing** the websocket connection. Note the **establishing part** is delayed - the delays in response packets are irrelevant in our scenario.
- Frontend was not even able to connect with servers `Y` and `Z` even though server health for `Y` and `Z` was healthy.

Our hunch is that due to HTTP 1.1 limit, 5 calls to `X` (2 HTTP and 3 Websocket connection attempts) hogged our frontend app by starving the other HTTP calls and websocket connection attempts to other backend servers `Y` and `Z`.

### Problem Statement

To test the same, we want to create a mock server that delays HTTP requests as well as Websocket requests - especially the websocket connection part should be delayed to simulate this scenario.

### What did I attempt?

I attempted the following, and it works well in delaying HTTP calls, but the websocket connection is immediately connected, just the response packets are delayed which is not what we want.

How to delay the websocket connection process?

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

// HTTP route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Simulate a 50-second delay
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.send('HTTP Response: 200 OK');
  }, 5000);
});

// WebSocket route
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    // Handle WebSocket messages
    console.log(`Received: ${message}`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      ws.send(`Received: ${message}`);
    }, 5000);
  });
});

// Start the combined server
server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Combined HTTP and WebSocket server running on port 8080');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `server.on('upgrade', cb)` to basically set the delay and then call `wss.handleUpgrade`. This way I was successfully able to create a delay in the websocket initialisation part.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });
const MOCK_DELAY_IN_MS = 50 * 1000;

// Middleware to introduce a 5-second delay for all HTTP GET requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    setTimeout(next, MOCK_DELAY_IN_MS);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

// Route to handle all GET requests
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('OK');
});

server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
  // Delay WebSocket connection for 5 seconds
  setTimeout(() => {
    wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
      wss.emit('connection', ws, request);
    });
  }, MOCK_DELAY_IN_MS);
});

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection established.');
  ws.on('message', (data) => {
    ws.send(`Received: ${data}`);
  });
  // Handle the WebSocket connection here
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 8080');
});
```